# Typescript: keyof type issue

Tags: typescript, keyof

For example, if I have this `User` model:

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  password: string;
  id: number;
}
```

and try to run this code:

```
let user = {
  firstName: 'string',
  lastName: 'string',
  age: 24,
  password: 'string',
  id: 0
}

let keys: keyof User[] = Object.keys(user) as keyof User[]; // this DOES NOT WORK

// keys: UserKeys[] = Object.keys(user) as UserKeys[];  // this works 

type UserKeys = keyof User;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Conversion of type `string[]` to type `number | keyof User[]` may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type `string[]` is not comparable to type `"includes"`
```

Here is [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAWACg450EpCYA5TAW2AC45GpkBzANxUaAG0yMW7Lj35DqcTH05wkAV1YAjNHJphxhAO7QAJtJi8kg4YlMr1WqHIC+VKiODxVxKHAC8ZazoGZjZlAHIZSzCAGmsxCVCuCPN+GOtFZQAmABZY+T1CQxMkyL40+QRbAAYqF0o3DzgAa2AAT0IuFtaIdAJvAG0AXT84AHkNACtgbBgAOi7CAAovNABKBUJmtp6+tCGBOAB6Q7hsTCQw+FZMFrgYAAsETaMoJv5XSmOt9q4iNABpNqEIYjcZTGbzIHLbzrcS7KCA9r7GhfB5PRDPaBvSxwD4wVpgPB-BFAkZdHbEgRAA) that reproduces the problem.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:** Found a [great article](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-better-object-keys/) connected with this issue.

Comment: Hello, if it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.** Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS. source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let keys: (keyof User)[] = Object.keys(this.user) as (keyof User)[];`

The problem is that `keyof User[]` is different than `UserKeys[]`. Though it's the same as `(keyof User)[]`

Comment: the problem was that, the `keyof User[]` is trying to get the keys of User Array, not the keys of User object. that's why the `()` make the work correct, thank you very much